# Wordpress Ajax - Js error 400(bad request)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

It's getting the link to the word press ajax file but giving me a bad request error.

The exact error im getting is POST http://[Website URL]/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Functions.php file

```
function as_custom_ajax_localizing() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/guest-list/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom.js', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'as_custom_ajax_localizing' );
```

Custom php file

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_delete_post', 'as_delete_guest' );
function as_delete_guest(){

    $permission = check_ajax_referer( 'as_delete_guest_nonce', 'nonce', false );
    if( $permission == false ) {
        echo 'error';
    } else {
        wp_delete_post( $_REQUEST['id'] );
        echo 'success';
    }

    die();

}
```

Custom Js file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".remove_guest" ).click(function() {

  var guestRowId = $(this).attr('id');
  alert( "This id is " + guestRowId + " and has been clicked");

  var nonce = $(this).data('nonce');

  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'my_delete_post',
            nonce: nonce,
            id: guestRowId
        },
        success: function( result ) {
            if( result == 'success' ) {
                alert("Success");
            }
            else{
                alert("problem");
            }
        }
    })
    return false;

});
});
```

Comment: why cant you try by passing direct url instead of MyAjax.ajaxurl, please check what the "MyAjax.ajaxurl" is alerting

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery's .post() instead of .ajax()? Also, I know WordPress ajax can be a pain to debug but have you tried just outputting something very simple from as_delete_guest() to make sure that file is working (without nonce)?